# Add class on div using foreach if else Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have 5 items ( 3 items on first row & 2 items on 2nd row ) that loads something like this

[image]

Here's my sample blade code

```
<div class="row">
                @if( !empty( $data ) )
                    @foreach( $data as $field )
                    
                        <div class="col-lg-4 services-overview-section__item">
                            <div class="services-overview-section__item--image">
                                <a href="{!! url('services-detail/'.$field->slug) !!}">
                                    <img src="{{url($field->banner_image) }}">

                                    <div class="services-overview-section__item--overlay">
                                        <h3>{!! $field->name !!}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="services-overview-section__item--content">
                                {!! $field->overview_description !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
      </div>
```

But what I'm trying to do is something like this

[image]

By doing this I need to add a class named as **'mid'** on this location

```
   <div class="col-lg-4 services-overview-section__item mid">
```

Tried to use something like this

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 services-overview-section__item {{ $loop->iteration % 2 == 0 ? 'mid' : '' }}">
```

But it doesn't give me the right output like what I expected.

I just want to add class 'mid' for every 2nd item of the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution :

```
<div class="row">
                @if( !empty( $data ) )
                    @php $itemThatNeedClass = 1; @endphp
                    @foreach( $data as $field )
                        @php
                            $customClass = "";
                            if ($loop->index === $itemThatNeedClass) {
                                $customClass = "mid";
                                $itemThatNeedClass += 3;
                            }
                        @endphp
                        <div class="col-lg-4 services-overview-section__item {{ $customClass }}">
                            <div class="services-overview-section__item--image">
                                <a href="{!! url('services-detail/'.$field->slug) !!}">
                                    <img src="{{url($field->banner_image) }}">

                                    <div class="services-overview-section__item--overlay">
                                        <h3>{!! $field->name !!}</h3>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="services-overview-section__item--content">
                                {!! $field->overview_description !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
      </div>
```

Comment: tried your answer, but only the first row 2nd item has the 'mid' class. 2nd row 2nd item doesn't have it https://prntscr.com/13x5mhe

Comment: Sorry i fixed it !

Comment: Try it again 